# Getting subject from id token in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have configured my Spring Boot application as a resource server. And it is working perfectly by blocking all the request that does not contain the authentication bearer token. However, once I am in service I would like to get the subject(sub in JWT token) out of the token an use it. How can I fetch the value of subject from Spring Authentication framework?

Since I am using Spring Boot's auto-configuration, I do not validate the token myself, it is been done automaticlly so I do not know the subject.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to test right now but i have an idea. I believe you can access with SecurityContext. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` gives you SecurityContext so  by accessing to Authentication obj, you should be able to get subject and so forth.

Comment: this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) helped me. And I found my answer. Basically you can put `Principal` to the controller argument and you will get the principle extracted for you. This is the beauty about spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;    
...
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I added Principle to the argument.

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserName(Principal principal) {
        return principal.getName();
    }
}
```

This [link](https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) helped me